# Error when trying to install devtools on Mac

Tags: r, macos, devtools

Does anyone has an idea on how to solve this problem? Can't install devtools in R.

> install.packages("devtools")
>   also installing the dependencies ‘ps’, ‘fs’, ‘processx’, ‘xopen’, ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘git2r’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘roxygen2’

- installing *source* package ‘fs’ ...
  ** package ‘fs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c error.cc -o error.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c dir.cc -o dir.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c utils.cc -o utils.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c link.cc -o link.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c path.cc -o path.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c file.cc -o file.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c fs.cc -o fs.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c id.cc -o id.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c unix/getmode.cc -o unix/getmode.o
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I./libuv/include -I. -pthread -I"/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/Rcpp/include" -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9  -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include  -fPIC  -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
  cp -p -f libuv/m4/lt_obsolete.m4 libuv/m4/lt~obsolete.m4
  (cd libuv \
  && touch aclocal.m4 \
  && touch -r aclocal.m4 configure Makefile.in \
  && CC="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang" CFLAGS="-march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -I/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/c099f90d-77ff-4dab-4625-1ec5b1f7533d/volume/r-base_1565121802879/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-3.6.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -fPIC " AR="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ar" RANLIB="x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-ranlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs  -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib -L/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib" ./configure --quiet)
  configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/s2/cptzh4ls2knbbd767m5gjx380000gn/T/RtmprlvVOz/R.INSTALL14a3b6572446a/fs/src/libuv':
  configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
  See`config.log' for more details
  make: *** [Makevars:32: libuv/Makefile] Error 77
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fs’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/fs’
  ERROR: dependency ‘ps’ is not available for package ‘processx’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/processx’
- installing *source* package ‘git2r’ ...
  ** package ‘git2r’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
  checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
  checking for gcc... x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang
  checking whether the C compiler works... no
  configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/s2/cptzh4ls2knbbd767m5gjx380000gn/T/RtmpfgNUT5/R.INSTALL14b4c40b5b5e8/git2r':
  configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
  See`config.log' for more details
  ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘git2r’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/git2r’
  ERROR: dependency ‘processx’ is not available for package ‘xopen’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/xopen’
  ERROR: dependencies ‘fs’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘usethis’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/usethis’
  ERROR: dependency ‘processx’ is not available for package ‘callr’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/callr’
  ERROR: dependency ‘callr’ is not available for package ‘pkgbuild’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/pkgbuild’
  ERROR: dependency ‘pkgbuild’ is not available for package ‘pkgload’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/pkgload’
  ERROR: dependencies ‘callr’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘xopen’ are not available for package ‘rcmdcheck’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/rcmdcheck’
  ERROR: dependency ‘pkgload’ is not available for package ‘roxygen2’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/roxygen2’
  ERROR: dependencies ‘usethis’, ‘callr’, ‘git2r’, ‘pkgbuild’, ‘pkgload’, ‘rcmdcheck’, ‘roxygen2’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
- removing ‘/Users/JoaoMoraes/miniconda3/lib/R/library/devtools’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/s2/cptzh4ls2knbbd767m5gjx380000gn/T/RtmpP8MNFU/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
There were 11 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

> warnings()
>   Warning messages:
>   1: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘fs’ had non-zero exit status
>   2: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘processx’ had non-zero exit status
>   3: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘git2r’ had non-zero exit status
>   4: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘xopen’ had non-zero exit status
>   5: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘usethis’ had non-zero exit status
>   6: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘callr’ had non-zero exit status
>   7: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘pkgbuild’ had non-zero exit status
>   8: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘pkgload’ had non-zero exit status
>   9: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘rcmdcheck’ had non-zero exit status
>   10: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘roxygen2’ had non-zero exit status
>   11: In install.packages("devtools") :
>     installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Do you have Xcode installed ? https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/devtools.html

Comment: Yes, Xcode is installed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using R on conda and was installing the package through CRAN.